# npm install -g surge then the respected error come up. please helps me to sort out this problem

Tags: node.js, npm

name: CI

on:
push:
branches: [ master ]

jobs:

build:

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest


        - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - name: Node js installation
    uses: actions/setup-node@v2-beta
    with:
      versoin: 14 
  
  - name: Installing Surge  
    run:  npm install --global surge
  
  - name: Yarn Installation
    uses: Borales/actions-yarn@v2.1.0
    with:
      cmd: install
  
  - name: Start building ...
    run: yarn build


  - name: Deplying site on surge...
    run: surge ./build  http://practice_of_bootcamp.surge.sh --token ${{secrets.SURGE_TOKEN}}
```

when this workflow flows the respected error come into the scope

Run npm install --global surge
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2020-11-05T05_49_12_767Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 243.

Comment: What part of `EACCES: permission denied: Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules` is unclear?

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved in two ways. Quickest would be to do `sudo npm install -g surge`. By using `sudo`, you're assuming root privileges temporarily. You may be asked for your user's password.

A much better way to solve this (and possibly never have this problem again) would be to install [node version manager (nvm)](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm). This involves a few steps to set up, but it'll install every thing - node, npm and all the global npm modules, to your user's folder, not the system level folders like `/usr/local`.

This becomes much easier to manage, and it's easy to nuke a node version and start anew. What's more, you get the ability to install multiple node version, and switch between them easily for a particular project or for all projects.